# Using RxJS operator to fetch from API and fetch another then combine the result

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am a beginner of RxJS and using angular for my Frontend. I have a case where I need to fetch a teams (Team[]).

And use that team id to fetch all the members (Member[]). And I need to return list of each team with members (Team, Member[]).

How do I do this with RxJS operator?

---

### For Example:

From Teams API: [{team_id: number, 'others'}, ...]

From Members API: [{member_id: number, member_name: string}, ...]

I need to combine the data to: [{team_id: number, members: [{member_id: number, member_name: string}, ...], ...]

Comment: you can chain both the requests and then iterate over the response and get desired result.

Comment: Why don't get the team with members from backend? If you gonna iterate one by one in front-end, it will be a performance issue. Do u have any relationship between team and members in db?

Comment: Do you need to get the members of each team? or just the first team in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.teamService.getTeams()
   .pipe(
     switchMap(teams => {
      // in here we will get all teams in teams variable
      const memberRequests = [];

      // we will create an array of member requests based on the teams
      teams.forEach(team => {

        const request = this.memberService.getMembersByTeamId(team.id)
          .pipe(map(members => { 
             // here we create new object which contains the team and its correspoing members
             return {...team, members} 
           }))

         memberRequests.push(request)
      })

      // in here we will call all member requests in parallel, and once all requests are completed we will get the response as array
      return forkJoin(memberRequests)
    }) 
   ).subscribe(items => {
     console.log(items)
   })
```

In the above code, you will get the teams and it's corresponding members as following,

> [{team_id: number, members: [{member_id: number, member_name: string},
>   ...], ...]

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `getTeams` and `getMember` method. Try the below code out see if it works.

```
getTeams().pipe(
    mergeMap(teams=>from(teams))
    mergeMap(team=> getMembers(team.id).pipe(map(members=>({...team,members}))),
    toArray()
)
```

Comment: how did the getMemeber requests is going to execute? parallelly?

Comment: yes. that's what mergeMap does , if you want sequential change the second one to concatMap

Comment: Yeah but will it wait for all the requests to complete? will the toArray() operator wait for that? or will it return the response on each time member api completes?

Comment: toArray will wait for all members requests completed, it is like push items to an empty array. Just a more concise approach.

Comment: Oh, then this should be the answer. this is more cleaner and better.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but please try it out.